# HTK Speech recognition integration with asterisk

Tags: asterisk

Kindly provide me some insight on integration of HTK digit recognition into Asterisl. I am new in this field. I will be highly obliged if anyone can help me out.

Comment: what is "HRK"? how you expect it be integrated into PBX?

Comment: Sorry its not HRK its HTK

Comment: Okay. So what is HTK?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have hire c++ expert. Since that toolkit even not ASR, just toolkit to build ASR.

So first you have write your own AST based on that toolkit, after that you have integrate that ASR with asterisk.

Also note this in FAQ

> Can I build & sell products based on HTK3?
>
> You may build a product but you are **not allowed** to **redistribute** (parts
>   of) HTK3, i.e. you can't ship shrink-wrap boxes with products that
>   contain HTK3 code.